# How to Update one column of Table B when inserting in Table A in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have two Tables Tbl_Appointment and Tbl_AppointmentRequest.
Data in Tbl_AppointmentRequest comes from mobile app, In UI there is a button approve when clicked it fills the textboxes, dropdown, etc with the data of Tbl_AppointmentRequest then there is a button called submit when I submit it inserts data into Tbl_Appointment and when it gets inserted there is a column isappconfirm in Tbl_AppointmentRequest which should be updated to 1.
Below is my Query, I'm able to Insert but unable to update isappconfirm column to 1.

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[Sp_Save_Appointment]
(@AppointmentID nvarchar(50),
@PatientID nvarchar(50),
@PatientName nvarchar(500),
--@PackageID nvarchar(50),
@PackageName nvarchar(500),
@Date nvarchar(50),
@Time nvarchar(50),
@DoctorID nvarchar(50),
@DoctorName nvarchar(500),
@HospitalName nvarchar(500),
@Address nvarchar(500),
@Price nvarchar(500),
@Latitude nvarchar(50),
@Longitude nvarchar(50),
@EscortName nvarchar(500),
@Createdby nvarchar(50),
@CreatedbyName nvarchar(500),
@Modifiedby nvarchar(50),
@ModifiedbyName nvarchar(500))
as begin
if(@AppointmentID='')
begin
Insert into Tbl_Appointment(PatientID,PatientName,PackageName,Date,Time,DoctorID,DoctorName,HospitalName,
Address,Price,Latitude,Longitude,EscortName,Createdby,CreatedbyName,CreatedDate)
values(@PatientID,(Select Top(1)PatientName from Tbl_Patientinfo where PatientID=@PatientID),
@PackageName,
@Date,@Time,@DoctorID,(Select Top(1) DoctorName from Tbl_DoctorInfo where DoctorID=@DoctorID),
@HospitalName,@Address,@Price,@Latitude,@Longitude,@EscortName,
@Createdby,(Select Top(1)UserName from Tbl_UserInfo where UserId=@Createdby),
convert(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+05:30')))
Declare @id nvarchar(20) set @id=@@identity
select @id as message
end

else
begin
Update Tbl_Appointment Set PatientID=@PatientID,@PatientName=(Select Top(1)PatientName from Tbl_Patientinfo where PatientID=@PatientID),
PackageName=@PackageName,
Date=@Date,Time=@Time,DoctorID=@DoctorID,DoctorName=(Select Top(1) DoctorName from Tbl_DoctorInfo where DoctorID=@DoctorID),
HospitalName=@HospitalName,Address=@Address,Price=@Price,Latitude=@Latitude,Longitude=@Longitude,EscortName=@EscortName,
Modifiedby=@Modifiedby,ModifiedbyName=@ModifiedbyName,ModifiedDate=convert(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+05:30'))
Where AppointmentID=@AppointmentID
Select '1' as message

declare @isappconfirm nvarchar(50)
set @isappconfirm=(select top(1) isappconfirm from Tbl_AppointmentRequest where AppointmentReqID=@AppointmentID order by AppointmentReqID desc)
if(@isappconfirm='')
begin
update Tbl_AppointmentRequest set isappconfirm='1' where AppointmentReqID=@AppointmentID
end


end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm astonished how people are unable to answer such a simple thing and pointing out and down voting when they are unable to answer and getting upvote for wrong answer.

It's very simple Just pass @AppointmentReqID and after declaring @isappconfirm then in where condition AppointmentReqID=@AppointmentReqID

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[Sp_Save_AppointmentRequest]
(@AppointmentID nvarchar(50),
@PatientID nvarchar(50),
@PatientName nvarchar(500),
@PackageName nvarchar(500),
@Date nvarchar(50),
@Time nvarchar(50),
@DoctorID nvarchar(50),
@DoctorName nvarchar(500),
@HospitalName nvarchar(500),
@Address nvarchar(500),
@Price nvarchar(500),
@Latitude nvarchar(50),
@Longitude nvarchar(50),
@EscortName nvarchar(500),
@Createdby nvarchar(50),
@CreatedbyName nvarchar(500),
@Modifiedby nvarchar(50),
@ModifiedbyName nvarchar(500),
@AppointmentReqID nvarchar(50))
as begin
if(@AppointmentID='')
begin


Insert into Tbl_Appointment(PatientID,PatientName,PackageName,Date,Time,DoctorID,DoctorName,HospitalName,
Address,Price,Latitude,Longitude,EscortName,Createdby,CreatedbyName,CreatedDate)
values(@PatientID,(Select Top(1)PatientName from Tbl_Patientinfo where PatientID=@PatientID),
@PackageName,
@Date,@Time,@DoctorID,(Select Top(1) DoctorName from Tbl_DoctorInfo where DoctorID=@DoctorID),
@HospitalName,@Address,@Price,@Latitude,@Longitude,@EscortName,
@Createdby,(Select Top(1)UserName from Tbl_UserInfo where UserId=@Createdby),
convert(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+05:30')))
Declare @id nvarchar(20) set @id=@@identity



declare @isappconfirm nvarchar(50)
set @isappconfirm=(select top(1) isappconfirm from Tbl_AppointmentRequest where AppointmentReqID=@AppointmentReqID order by AppointmentReqID desc)
if(@isappconfirm='NULL')
begin
update Tbl_AppointmentRequest set isappconfirm='1' where AppointmentReqID=@AppointmentReqID
end
select @id as message
end

else
begin

Update Tbl_Appointment Set PatientID=@PatientID,@PatientName=(Select Top(1)PatientName from Tbl_Patientinfo where PatientID=@PatientID),
PackageName=@PackageName,
Date=@Date,Time=@Time,DoctorID=@DoctorID,DoctorName=(Select Top(1) DoctorName from Tbl_DoctorInfo where DoctorID=@DoctorID),
HospitalName=@HospitalName,Address=@Address,Price=@Price,Latitude=@Latitude,Longitude=@Longitude,EscortName=@EscortName,
Modifiedby=@Modifiedby,ModifiedbyName=@ModifiedbyName,ModifiedDate=convert(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+05:30'))
Where AppointmentID=@AppointmentID
Select '1' as message


end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting Data in **Tbl_Appointment** .

SO, you will get new identity key (**new AppointmentID**) which is **not available in Tbl_AppointmentRequest**.
That's why this is not working.

For this, You also have to add **new entry** on **Tbl_AppointmentRequest** related to **inserted AppointmentID** and set **isappconfirm=1**.
So new entry will add in Tbl_AppointmentRequest with isappconfirm=1 on insertion.
That's it.

Comment: @murtuza please try above query. i updated that query.

Comment: @murtuza

is there data in Tbl_AppointmentRequest for related AppointmentID ? Please check..

Comment: data in Tbl_AppointmentRequest is coming from mobile app then from database i'am sending it to UI fields then when i submit it should insert into Tbl_Appointment and when successfully inserted it should update the isappconfirm column to 1,but its simply getting inserted without updating isappconfirm column @kgajjar20

Comment: AppointmentID is generated after data gets inserted @kgajjar20

Comment: @murtuza

You are inserting Data in Tbl_Appointment .

SO, you will get new identity key (new AppointmentID) which is not available in Tbl_AppointmentRequest. That's why this is not working.

For this, You also have to add new entry on Tbl_AppointmentRequest related to inserted AppointmentID and set isappconfirm=1. So new entry will add in Tbl_AppointmentRequest with isappconfirm=1 on insertion. That's it.